# Cakephp send variables from view to controller

Tags: variables, cakephp, send

I create an xml file in the action createfile() with name $filename.

I send the variable to the view createfile.ctp and show it.

Then i need to send that $filename variable to another action of the controller.

I have this code:

Controller:

```
function createfile()
{
...
$this->set('filename', $filename);
}
```

View:

```
<h1>Result:</h1>
<?php echo $filename;
<?= $this->Html->link('Continue.', ['action' => 'edit']) ?>
```

I dont want to send the variable with GET. I dont want to show ir in the url.

I have tried with this lines in the view:

```
<?php $this->set('filename', $filename);?>
```

or

```
<?php $this->Form->hidden('filename', array('value' => $filename)); ?>
```

or

```
<?php echo $this->request->session()->write('filename', $filename);?>
```

(this last one makes the session fail).

But in the other action of the controller, the $filename is always empty.

there is another line to pass variables? 
Thanks.

Comment: Your second approach should work.  Are you checking the value of `$this->request->data`?  The value of `$filename` should be present in `$this->request->data['ModelName']['filename']`

Comment: I tried $xmlfile = Xml::build($this->request->data('filename')); That makes an error because $filename is empty. $filename is just a variable, does not belong to a Model.

Comment: try dumping `$this->request->data` to see its structure.  You can assign any variable to a form input value, it doesn't have to belong to a model.  I think it will still index `$this->request->data` based on what model you specify in `$this->Form->create`, regardless of whether `filename belongs to a model.  Also, `$this->Form->hidden('SomeModel.filename', ...` will create `$this->request->data['SomeModel']['filename']` regardless of what `filename` is.

Comment: Another issue is that in you comment you tried to access `$this->request->data` as if it was a function, using parenthesis, `$this->request->data('filename')`.  You need to use square brackets to access array indexes in php.  `$this->request->data['SomeIndex']`

Comment: In your case you have to use session variables that forwarding between two actions

Comment: I tried that at the beginning but it throws exception and the session closed.